# Javascript: get element by class but skip a certain class

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I want to select an element having a certain class but without a certain other class. You would do this with a cool CSS3 selector

```
self.tabs.querySelector('.active:not(.dropdown)')
```

but this won't work in IE9- so I am looking for something like this

```
self.tabs.querySelector('.active') && !self.tabs.querySelector('.dropdown')
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: If there isn't a selector, I would assume you just filter the results in a loop based on the classes they have.

Comment: The :not pseudo-selector should work in IE9+ [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). If you need to support pre-IE9, then you will have to filter in js as the previous poster said.

Comment: It depends on what you need to do, but I agree with @AR7 firstly get the element you need in a collection then loop through them to get the collection you need with JQuery .hasClass('dropdown').  Again, the not selector should actually work in IE9.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, toggling tabs, we don't need a loop to filter the exact element we need because there will never be more than 2 `active` elements and it's enough to only use one level sub navigation. So to sum up, the code would look like this.

```
var activeTabs = self.tabs.querySelectorAll('.active');
if ( activeTabs.length === 1 && !activeTabs[0].classList.contains('dropdown') ) {
    return activeTabs[0]
} else if ( activeTabs.length > 1 ) {
    return activeTabs[1] 
// or return activeTabs[activeTabs.length-1]
// in case we need the exact item that is relevant to the tab content and is on even deeper level
}
```

Hope this helps someone.